# How do I call a function within my class?

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I'm trying to practice classes in python by trying to make a class which normalizes the currency to all GBP using an exchnage rate table. I'm not sure why i'm getting the below error. CurrencyCombo is a column name in the exchnagerate table which i pass into init as 'CurrencyPairCol'

```
rateList = ['EURGBP','USDGBP', 'SEKGBP']
Month = ['2018-11', '2018-12', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03']

class CurrencyNormalize():

    def __init__(self,filename,rateList,monthList,orders_filename,CurrencyPair):
        self.ExchangeRate = pd.read_csv(filename)
        self.OrdersTrain = pd.read_csv(orders_filename)
        self.rateList=rateList
        self.monthList=monthList
        self.currencyPairCol=self.ExchangeRate[CurrencyPair]

    def remove_char(self):

        return (self.replace('GBP', ''))


    def normalize(self):
        ExchangeRateFilt= self.ExchangeRate[self.ExchangeRate.CurrencyCombo.isin(self.rateList)]
        monthOnly= ExchangeRateFilt[ExchangeRateFilt.TradeMonth.isin(self.monthList)]
        print(monthOnly['CurrencyCombo'])
        monthOnly['CurrencyCombo] = monthOnly['CurrencyCombo].apply(self.remove_char())
```

I want to apply the function remove_char in the normalize function but i'm not sure if i'm doing it wrong. WHen i run the above as follows:

```
CurrencyNormalize('MonthlyExchangeRates.csv',rateList,Month,'Orderss.csv','CurrencyCombo').normalize()
```

I  get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'CurrencyNormalize' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I think the error has something to do with how i appply the remove_char function, before i tried the OOP way the function was:

```
def remove_char(col):#


    return (col.replace('GBP', ''))
```

and i would call it as :

```
ExchangeRate['CurrencyCombo'].apply(remove_char)
```

where Exchange rate is the df. How do i generalilse the function remove_char within the class?

Comment: You haven't set CurrencyCombo to anything from what I can see

Comment: Itr's the name of the column from exchange rate table.. how do i set it such that there are no quotation marks around it?

Comment: @Maths12 is CurrencyCombo supposed to be a variable or the column name? (i.e. a string)

Comment: @Gio it's meant to be a column name

Comment: print `self.ExchangeRate.columns` to be sure the column is in there, sometimes whitespace can mess up with column names

Comment: @Maths12 then you should call it as a string: `CurrencyNormalize('MonthlyExchangeRates.csv',rateList,Month,'Orderss.csv','CurrencyCombo').normalize() 
`

Comment: @Gio due to the remove_char function it needs to be stripped of it's columns quotation marks.

Comment: @IanS when i print that i get: Index(['TradeMonth', 'CurrencyCombo', 'ExchangeRate'], dtype='object')

Comment: @Gio has it right

Comment: @Maths12 I think you have an error in `__init__`. I believe you want to assign to the parameter `currencyPairCol` the whole column (with values) taken from the imported csv. However, the command `self.currencyPairCol=CurrencyPairCol` simply assigns the column name to the parameter `currencyPairCol`

Comment: @Gio please see my edit.. when i revistited how i did it before i tried this OOP way i think the main issue is i'm unaware how to apply the remove_char function in the OOP way, where col in the remove_char function is just anything, how do i generalise it

Comment: @Maths12 too long for a comment. I'll post an answer and we improve from there. I can't replicate your code unless you provide a sample of the csv you are importing

Answer (score 1):

`self` refers to your class. When you call `self.replace()` you are trying to run the method `replace` (which doesn't exist). What you want to do is something like:

```
self.ExchangeRate[CurrencyPair].replace('GBP', '')
```

EDIT: Since you correctly defined the attribute `currencyPairCol` you can simply call:

```
self.currencyPairCol.replace('GBP', '')
```

Clearly, the latter will modify only the attribute `currencyPairCol` and not the originally imported dataframe `ExchangeRate` (nor the column `CurrencyPair` in it)